# Angular Material layout nested flex rows inside of flex columns do not divide space as expected

Tags: css, angularjs, flexbox, angular-material

I am trying to layout my window so that the outer div fills the height of the window. It should be divided into two columns: 65% on the left and 35% on the right. The right column should be divided into three rows: the top one is flexible, the middle one should be 15% and the bottom one should be 20%.

The odd thing is that the outer column configuration works fine (the 65/35 split) but the vertical splits are not working as expected.

I am testing in Chrome and only need to support Chrome.

Here is the HTML I thought should work:

```
<div layout="row" flex ng-app="sandbox">
    <div layout="column" flex="65">
        flex-65
    </div>
    <div layout="column">
        <div layout="row" flex>
            flex
        </div>
        <div layout="row" flex="15">
            flex-15
        </div>
        <div layout="row" flex="20">
            flex-20
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is a plnkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/XWNfOVHvCoBwVeE2krdK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome doesn't calculate vertical percentages very well in Flexbox. So remove the following and let the default `align-self: stretch` do its magic.

```css
.layout-fill {
  height: 100%; /* Remove this and use `auto` instead */
}
```

For the inner elements, you use a percentage `flex-basis`, which is buggy too on Chrome. Better use a 0 flex-basis and distribute the available space using flex-grow factors:

```css
.layout-column > .flex    { flex: 65; }
.layout-column > .flex-15 { flex: 15; }
.layout-column > .flex-20 { flex: 20; }
```

[Fixed Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1qgxdZC3uSA51R4kkL0v)

Comment: This worked, thank you. Is there a way to track this in Chrome to know when the issue is fixed? caniuse.com just shows Chrome as green.

Comment: @JBCP No idea. Note Flexbox is still a draft in development.